# IS the Intel 80GB X25-M SATA II MLC SSD - SSDSA2MH080G2R5 compatible with Dell D630?

Tags: ssd

IS the Intel 80GB X25-M SATA II MLC SSD SSDSA2MH080G2R5 compatible with Dell D630 laptop? somehow the pins look different..

Answer (score 3):

After looking up the specification, it has a SATA hard drive, so you should have no problems swapping it for a SSD.

Answer (score 1):

The drive has a SATA 2 interface. This means that it is compatible with **all** motherboards that have a SATA or SATA 2 interface since SATA is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I've put the same SSD in my MacBook Pro ! The only thing you have to check is if your laptop supports sata hard drives !